# Angular.JS: Data not getting updated in Angular for Popups

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to do a Pop-up in Angular.js with a table, where there is an option to click in a particular cell in a row which gives a pop-up. Below is the code snip.

Html code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr><th>Number</th><th>Comment</th></tr><tr ng-repeat="col in Data|filter:search1"><td>{{col.cd}}</td><td><div ng-controller="igCtrl"> 

    <a href="#" ng-click="addComment(col.cd)">Comment</a>

    <ig-comment></ig-comment>
</div></td></tr></table>
```

Controller

```
function igCtrl($scope) {
$scope.addComment = function (col) {
$scope.cdn="";

                $scope.cdn = col;  



console.log("testing"+$scope.cdn);
$scope.check = true;
if ($scope.check) {
                $("#comment").modal('show');

            };

};}
```

Directive

```
app.directive('igComment', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
template:'<div class="row">
 <div class="modal fade" id="comment" aria-hidden = "true" > 
     <div class = "modal-dialog" style="width:300px;height:600px;">  
          <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit = "submit()" novalidate="novalidate">  
              <div class = "modal-content" > 
                  <div class = "modal-header">
                       Data is :{{cdn}}    

                       <input ng-disabled="form.$invalid"    type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" ng-click="submit()" value="Submit"></input >
                       <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" ng-click="cancel()"></input>
                  </div>
                </div >
            </form>
        </div >
    </div>
</div>'
 };
});
```

Data for this table is coming from the database. The variable `cdn` in the controller is getting updated and the `console.log` statement in the controller gives correct output.

But `cdn` in the directive is not getting updated and hence not showing rite results in the pop-up.

How to rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an isolated scope for this. 
e.g.:

```html
<ig-comment cdn="cdn"></ig-comment>
```

* this takes the "cdn" value from the controller's scope

and in the directive:

```
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       scope: { cdn: '=' } // this assigns the "cdn" from the directive attribute above
                           // to the directive isolated scope (under the same name)
       ...
```

The rest seems fine (ignoring the unfortunate jquery mix) and should work.

Comment: Thank you :) It did not solved my problem, but helped me  for a better understanding :)